# Can I create a content type that incorporates multiple files and an image?

Tags: content-type

The SharePoint 2010 content type I would like to create is a "Logo", which has a thumbnail image and 2 files associated with (a JPG and an EPS file). As I understand it, I can't have a site column of the type "binary", but I don't want to have to separately upload the 2 files to a document library, then upload the thumbnail to a publishing images list, then connect all 3 items under one content type with 3 lookup columns.

Do I have another option? Is there a way I can do all of this in one place?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a [document set](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx).  A document set is a content type comprised of multiple items.